# Error when using bind_param with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Why am I getting an error with this code?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO buku VALUES (
        NULL,
        (SELECT id_penerbit FROM penerbit WHERE nm_penerbit = ?),
        (SELECT id_pengarang FROM pengarang WHERE nm_pengarang = ?),
        (SELECT id_kategori FROM kategori WHERE nm_kategori = ?),
        (SELECT id_lemari FROM lemari WHERE nm_lemari = ?),
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssisss", $penerbit, $pengarang, $kategori, $lemari, $judul, $isbn, $hal, $terbit, $bahasa, $sinopsis);
if($stmt->execute()) showAlert("Berhasil mengubah kategori", "success");
else showAlert($stmt->error);
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in     C:\xampp\htdocs\eperpus\admin\buku-tambah.php on line 34

Comment: Is `$mysqli` initialized properly?

Comment: ya, already require in my header.php

Comment: Then your query is failing and the prepare call results in a failure. Check your query

Comment: Simply add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` before creating the `$mysqli` instance to have all your errors well reported in the way of exceptions

Comment: Looks to me like you simply haven't closed off the `VALUES` list with a closing parenthesis, ie `)`. Voting to close as a *typo*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `->bind_param()` on a non-object - which means there was an error in creating the object (`$stmt`) and it returned `false` - [as documented](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

The only way to troubleshoot the problem would be to investigate why the `->prepare()` call failed - an issue which is a tad bit hard to troubleshoot as an outsider with only access to one line of code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO buku VALUES (NULL, (SELECT id_penerbit FROM penerbit WHERE nm_penerbit = ?), (SELECT id_pengarang FROM pengarang WHERE nm_pengarang = ?), (SELECT id_kategori FROM kategori WHERE nm_kategori = ?), (SELECT id_lemari FROM lemari WHERE nm_lemari = ?), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, ?");
```

**Edit**: The query itself is bad, as it doesn't close the `VALUES (` parenthesis. This was the issue.

Comment: thanks, im already searching 1 hour where im wrong. my query should work.
im already test it on phpmyadmin.

Comment: Actually, it's very easy to troubleshoot... `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...); if (!$stmt) throw new Exception($mysqli->error, $mysqli->errno);` or dial up the error reporting as mentioned in my comment above

Comment: @anonprophet, @Phil's previous comment with `mysqli_report` may be your best shot. Just because the query is right (maybe its wrong, don't throw it out the window) doesn't mean something else isn't wrong.

Comment: FYI - the query is syntactically erroneous

Comment: @Phil good catch, I didn't see that. I'll leave up my answer JIC somebody else comes and wants to troubleshoot a problem without a bad query, as it is still valid.